Ultraviolet Movie
What is the best material for a screen using an Ultra-violet light projector? I need a material/screen that can convert UV light into a visible light to best look like a normal movie theater screen image. Some TVs use this already to produce more vibrant color but I am interested in using a UV projector and screen alone to produce an image.

You could simply use paper doped with a dilute uv absorber solution of such as sodium salicylate or 9-10 diphenyl-anthracene or perylene  that have a blue fluorescence that will respond just as rapidly as the image changes.  BTW you should be aware that uv light below about 300nm can really damage the eyes causing cataracts.

In thin layer chromatography (TLC), plates coated with silica, or alumina often include such an inorganic fluorescent manganese doped zinc silicate dye which is activated by black light/UV light of $\pu{254 nm}$ wavelength:

(figure source Wikipedia)
There still are a few labs going this extra mile to prepare their TLC plates on-site, which either purchase the $\ce{Al2O3}$ powder including this salts (example), or purchase these salts directly for instance at Macherey-Nagel, or from your supplier of chemicals (example VWR).
In the picture above, the dark spots are the places where compounds absorbing UV radiation itself are adsorbed; they attenuate the exciting UV light.
Outside the chemical lab, there are a couple of other blacklight paints, and pigments

(image credit everyglow.com)
to paint and mark items (think for instance of security paper used in passports, banknotes, tickets; example), or even makeup

(image credit medusasmakeup.com)

Great answer,it looks like glow in the dark material. UV and regular light can illuminate that, but their are other colors and ranges shades available. Maybe a mix of reactive material is needed with less retention can be had?

@Justintimeforfun The hint to the glow materials was a good one to edit and extend the answer a little.  Though the materials used surely vary (I speculate salts of rare metals are fine on banknotes, but not so much in cosmetics).

Yeah, the one thing I might say against this angle is that the decay time on the fluorescence is probably far too long to be any good for showing a movie.
A still image, maybe.
You might be able to get away with some kind of interlacing approach like old phosphor dot TVs used to do, but your framerate still isn't going to be amazing.

@ConnieMnemonic Huh? The green of TLC plates with an UV indicator goes away the moment I switch off the black light. This aside, (singlet to singlet) fluorescence is a fast process and hence used in modern OLED (TV) screens (typical frame rate of 120 Hz), or FLIM microscopy. Phosphorescence, with intersystem crossing between triplet and singlet states, is the slower one (minutes, hours); this is somewhere between «doesn't matter (so much)» for a reading lamp, and «useful» (tools, non radioactive dials of wrist watches, though its excitation can be (e.g., trigalight).

Ach, ignore me. I'm not a chemist and make the ignorant mistake of seeing the colour/paints and assuming this was just the same material as glow-in-the-dark stars and the like. Thanks for educating me!
